# What does "crayon is forever." mean?

Tags: meaning, quotes

> History written in pencil is easily erased, but crayon is forever. *Emilie Autumn*

What does "crayon is forever." mean?

Comment: It sounds sarcastic, but in order to assess the statement (and divine its meaning) a bit more context would be nice.

Comment: @ChenDavid These are poor questions. You must supply context, and you must show that you have at least done some research of your own.

Comment: Have you ever tried erasing a crayon mark?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a joke, making a general statement that sounds like it's philosophically profound, and then following up with a mundane remark about the difficulty of getting crayon off of walls/upholstery if you have small children (or indeed if you don't have small children, but then you wouldn't have crayon on your walls). But without context it could be anything.

Comment: This might have been better on our [literature.se] site.

Answer (score 2):

The quote is from Emilie August's novel "*The Asylum for Wayward Victorian Girls*".

The reference to crayon is almost certainly made because inmates in asylums were only allowed crayon as a writing instrument (because it's very hard to hurt yourself or someone else with a crayon). In Victorian times children and young people were often committed to asylums not for any genuine mental problem but for socially undesirable or inconvenient behaviour.

It is possible that the history being referred to is people's own personal history, and "crayon" (the writing implement of the asylum) is being contrasted with "pencil" (the writing implement of the Victorian schoolchild), and meaning that your time in school may be easily forgotten, but your time in an asylum will be remembered forever. Or it may be an assertion that the history of the asylum inmates will not be easily forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

- Pencil – inarguably erasable
- Crayon – cannot be erased

Think of the color pencil leaves – grey, so it is very dull as compared to the colors that crayons can leave. The *colors* here could allude to the ardour, the  colorful happenings of human civilization, whereas those happenings in the past which play insignificant roles are monotone, and therefore easily forgotten.

Comment: It wasn't meant to be sentence, but somehow they ended up in one line.

Comment: If you're referring to formatting, the trick is to leave a blank line between paragraphs when typing. Consecutive lines of text (without a blank line in between) will be rendered as if there wasn't a line break. (If you're referring merely to sentence length, please ignore this comment.)

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing does not follow standard formal syntax of English, but it is 'the way you say it' even if it is a bit informal.

In

> History written in pencil is easily erased, but crayon is forever.

the second phrase is an elision of the more detailed:

> but *history written in* crayon is forever.

There are two interesting parts about this that are informal. One is the use of 'crayon' as a [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) of the longer 'history written in crayon'. It's just a clever way of shortening a phrase.

As to '...is forever', that is style that your high school teacher would mark in red and your newspaper editor would fire you for, but informally sounds just fine. What those two would suggest instead is '... *lasts* forever'. Which is perfectly standard and formal and boring.